# Accessing Text File that is an external database for a Linked Table in Access

Tags: java, ms-access, printwriter, linked-tables

I have a rather specific problem involving the Bloomberg API, a java .jar project, a text file and a linked table in Access.

Basically I am working on a java project that is responsible for subscribing to a bunch of currency related data, manipulating it, then constantly outputting updated data on 10 second intervals to a text file. That text file is then used as an external database for an Linked Table in Access and that data is used with queries there.

The problem I have encountered is that I am using the PrintWriter class to output the data to the text file, and it does that by just recreating the text file with the outputted data every 10 seconds.

I had created the access database with a text file that wasn't being constantly updated, but now I realize when I run the java project, it outputs perfectly fine, but when I open the query the java project crashes because it can't access the text file.

Does anyone know of a way to overcome this problem or perhaps using a different method/function to output the data from java?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you show in a code sample where the problem appears?

Comment: Not sure if this will work for you but a thought might be to have **Access** copy the file (with VBA) and then have it work with the copied file instead. Trap and ignore access violations within your Java application if the file coping interferes with writes to the file and buffer/queue those writes to take place on the next available file write....or something like that. :/

Comment: What is the importance of using a text file and then write its contants to the database? Why can't the Java program write the output data directly to the Access database?  Also, can I know why 10 sec interval and why not more (or even less)?